# How do I send an object to a JSF page?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

Each row in the table below represents an Auction. For each Auction there are a number of Offers (so a `@ManyToOne` relationship between **Offers** and **Auctions**).

The blue button means **"Add Offer"**. When the user clicks "Add Offer" I want to open a form (in a new page) that the user fills in order to add an offer **to the correspondng auction**.

**How do I send the current row Auction object to the Add Offer .xhtml form?**

In PHP for example I would just send the corresponding Auction ID in the URL (the button would be a link `<a href='add_offer?auction_id=123' role='button'>`, and then I would use `$_GET['auction_id']` to retrieve the corresponding auction's id).

*Sorry if my question is stupid, I'm new to JavaEE.*

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the mapping?

Comment: @SujalMandal Yes, how do I map a new Offer to a specific Auction (the one on the corresponding row on the table), when I persist a new Offer?

Comment: Given your PHP comparison, it sounds like you're more asking about the web framework being used than about JPA. JPA doesn't at all generate HTML code. You normally use e.g. JSF or JSP for this. You should ignore the JPA part and reframe the question to ask how to pass the current row object to the controller when clicking a button in a table. Once you have that answer, the rest you need to do in JPA should speak for itself.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for rephrasing, this is exactly what I need! I'll edit the question.